# ionic footer input field being hidden by keyboard in chat app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic in my phonegap app and a funny thing is happening in my phonegap build to google play that's not happening when i install the app tethered to a usb. I think it might be caused by a difference in setting in my config file locally from the one I upload to pg.

Here's the problem: I'm using this input in a footer

```
<ion-footer-bar>
    <label class="item-input-wrapper nobgcolor">
        <input type="text" ng-model="IM.textMessage" placeholder="Type in your message...">
    </label>
        <button ng-click="sendMessage(IM.textMessage)" class="button button-small button-balanced">
            Send
    </button>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

It rides up along the keyboard on my android phone, which is what it's supposed to do when I start typing. But now that the app is live in google play, the keyboard hides the footer making it very awkward to type.

If anyone has run into this, i'd appreciate your input. If you think it might be something in my config.xml, I can post the parts I think are the most relevant.

Comment: What do you mean it *rides up along the keyboard*? Can you include some screenshots?

Comment: The input field is supposed stay visible on top of the phones keypad while you're typing and not disappear like what's happening on my live app when I install it from google. I suspect it's one of the configurations in my config file but not sure which one. And I'd rather not do process of elimination. I'l get some screens, but that's that basic problem

Comment: It seems like the on screen keyboard is obscuring the input field. Is your input within a Scroll View? Ionic should automatically try to prevent the keyboard from doing this. Also, instead of submitting it to Google Play each time you could use `ionic run android` to immediately test on an attached USB device.

Comment: Yes, I've been testing using usb like that and I don't see this problem. That's why I think it's something in the config file i'm uploading to phonegap build. I've been trying to compare the differences in the two config files - the one I use locally and the one on phonegap. I've identified one possible cause:  <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" /> I've since changed that value to false since that's how it looks in my local config I use with usb

Comment: For Ionic 5 with capacitor, Please check out this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989188/ionic-4-show-footer-above-the-keyboard/65967783#65967783

Answer (score 4):

This goes out out to anyone that's had a similar problem with the ionic footer and inputs in cordova build. If you have this preference in config.xml

```
 <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

The keyboard will hide the input when it's activated. If you absolutely need to see that input when typing (that was a joke) than just set it to false and it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this properties to your ionicModule in app.module.ts. works for me.

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      scrollAssist: false, 
      autoFocusAssist: false
    })
```