# ionic 4 show footer above the keyboard

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[image][image]I have a problem with the keyboard in my application ionic 4.
the text box in the footer is hidden when the keyboard is displayed, which makes it impossible to see what is written in the text box.

[without keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dpm3.png)

[when the keyboard is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX0zM.png)

thank you for proposing a solution to my problem

Comment: Please share your markup

Comment: I already added the footer code in my post

Answer (score 1):

i am pretty certain you have you application in fullscreen mode if so please remove the full screen mode as it does not go with ionic 4 footer inputs.

Comment: I remove the fullscreen mode on config.xml but I already have the same error

Comment: dont forget to set the keyboard to ionic.

Comment: how to do it? because I tried a lot of solution but without success

Comment: <preference name="KeyboardResize" value="true" /> 
<preference name="KeyboardResizeMode" value="Ionic" />

Comment: something things like superbar get in the way and other plugins

Comment: Thank you, after many hours of frustration the solution was so simple, I've remove fullscreen from <ion-content>and MAGIC!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Using a regular `<input type="text">` instead of `<ion-input type="text">`. That was easy fix for me on ionic 3.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I'm falling on an error...... {Template parse errors:
Void elements do not have end tags "input" ("-toolbar>        
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="message" placeholder="Write your message ...">[ERROR ->]</input>  
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button (click)="sendMessage()">}

Answer (score 0):

Working solution for Ionic 5 with capacitor,
Adding listener on keyboard events, we can toggle the whole ion-footer element to transform up or down.
Note the minus sign in translate3d keyboardHeight.

```
import { Plugins, KeyboardInfo } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Keyboard } = Plugins;

@ViewChild(IonFooter, { read: ElementRef }) private inputTextArea: ElementRef

  ionViewDidEnter() {

    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', (info: KeyboardInfo) => {
      console.log('keyboard will show with height', info.keyboardHeight);
      this.inputTextArea.nativeElement.style.setProperty(
        'transform',
        `translate3d(0, -${info.keyboardHeight}px, 0)`
      );
    });

    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', () => {
      console.log('keyboard did hide');
      this.inputTextArea.nativeElement.style.removeProperty('transform');
    });
}
```

Comment: is this till valid two years later?

Comment: There are some changes in the latest ionic capacitor Plugin import and usage. other than that should be working.

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0#accessibility-app-and-modals-plugins-split-up